# Does the Wizard Talent Conflagration work with weapons with +Fire Damage?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The Wizard Passive skill [Conflagration](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/conflagration) causes enemies hit by fire damage to take increased damage:

> Fire damage dealt to enemies applies a burning effect, increasing all damage done to them by 10% for 3 seconds.

Can attacks from spells that don't normally do Fire Damage trigger this effect if a weapon with the Fire Damage property is equipped? If so, does this apply to all attacks, or only those which don't already have a specified damage type, such as [Spectral Blade](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/spectral-blade)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skills that state "% weapon damage" will deal the elemental damage from a weapon. Skills that state "% weapon damage as (element)" will not. So the weapon's fire damage would come through with Spectral Blade, but not with Magic Missile or Ray of Frost.

If the skill deals fire damage, either "naturally" or from a weapon effect, it should activate Conflagration.

Some sources [here](http://forums.forcestrategygaming.com/showthread.php?1824-Question-about-Paralysis-and-Conflagration), [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149177066), [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4768449923).

Comment: So, this doesn't really answer my main question at all, just the qualifier I mentioned at the end.

Comment: @LessPopMoreFizz - I have attempted to clarify.